# Moment.js - two dates difference in number of days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I get incorrect results when trying to find numeric difference between two dates:

```
var startDate = moment( $('[name="date-start"]').val(), "DD.MM.YYYY"), // $('[name="date-start"]').val() === "13.04.2016"
endDate       = moment( $('[name="date-end"]'  ).val(), "DD.MM.YYYY"); // $('[name="date-end"]').val() === "28.04.2016"

var diff = startDate.diff(endDate);

console.log( moment(diff).format('E') );
```

Between `13.04.2016` and `28.04.2016` I shouldn't get that difference is **3** or **2** days...

I've tried to multiple combinations:

- swap `startDate.diff(endDate)` with `endDate.diff(startDate)`
- `format('E')` with something I've come up searching the SO

Result: all the time I get that difference is 3 or 2 days.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

From the moment.js [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/): `format('E')` stands for day of week. thus your diff is being computed on which day of the week, which has to be between 1 and 7.

From the moment.js docs again, here is what they suggest:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Here is a JSFiddle for your particular case:

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  var startDate = moment("13.04.2016", "DD.MM.YYYY");
  var endDate = moment("28.04.2016", "DD.MM.YYYY");

  var result = 'Diff: ' + endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');

  $('#result').html(result);
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffb;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id='test'>Click Me!!!</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: ok, but how do I get that difference between these two dates are 15 days? Thanks for answer

Comment: Updated my answer... do check and let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for solution, but now I would have to add a lot of code to get that array since what I get from `$('input[name="date-start"]').val()` is `"13.04.2016"`. Is there any solution that would work with my current date format?

Comment: @Miloshio : No need to use it exactly as defined in the documentation. You can use your own Moment. I included a jsfiddle which should help clarify.

Comment: @Miloshio : does the example help or are you still facing problems?

Answer (score 10):

Here's how you can get the comprehensive full fledge difference of two dates.

```
 function diffYMDHMS(date1, date2) {

    let years = date1.diff(date2, 'year');
    date2.add(years, 'years');

    let months = date1.diff(date2, 'months');
    date2.add(months, 'months');

    let days = date1.diff(date2, 'days');
    date2.add(days, 'days');

    let hours = date1.diff(date2, 'hours');
    date2.add(hours, 'hours');

    let minutes = date1.diff(date2, 'minutes');
    date2.add(minutes, 'minutes');

    let seconds = date1.diff(date2, 'seconds');

    console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days ' + hours + ' 
    hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds'); 

    return { years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds};
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `moment.js` to find the difference between two dates in days.

Install moment.js using the following command,

```
npm install moment
```

Calculate the difference between two dates in days.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var date1 = moment("2022-10-30");
var date2 = moment("2022-12-30");
var days = date1.diff(date2, 'days')
```

Comment: I agreed, but your example may return days in the negative. The best way to use the second date after the first date. like var days = date2.diff(date1, 'days')

Answer (score 0):

the `diff` method returns the difference in milliseconds. Instantiating `moment(diff)` isn't meaningful.

You can define a variable :

```
var dayInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

and then use it like so :

```
diff / dayInMilliseconds // --> 15
```

**Edit**

actually, this is built into the `diff` method, dubes' answer is better

Comment: This helped a lot, let me see if I'd go this way

Answer (score 0):

```
const FindDate = (date, allDate) => {
        
    // moment().diff only works on moment(). Make sure both date and elements in allDate array are in moment format
    let nearestDate = -1; 
    
    allDate.some(d => {
        const currentDate = moment(d)
        const difference = currentDate.diff(d); // Or d.diff(date) depending on what you're trying to find
        if(difference >= 0){
            nearestDate = d
        }
    });
    
    console.log(nearestDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the differance in Seconds

```
var date1 = moment("2022-10-30");
var date2 = moment("2022-12-30");
var diff = date1.diff(date2, 'seconds')
```

**and then you can conver then in to hours and Minutes and seconds.**

```
var mind = diff % (60 * 60);
const hours = Math.floor(diff / (60 * 60));
const minutes = Math.floor(mind / 60);
var seconds = Math.ceil(mind % 60);
```

Thanks