# Difference between two dates moment.js

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have a formatted `date` that comes as a string `"19/04/2018"` I need to compare it with the date today and know how many days have passed.

I'm trying it this way but it does not work properly.

```
var stringDate =  $scope.dataAddOutpatient.date; //Return "19/04/2018" 
var today = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
var date = moment(stringDate);

//Difference in number of days
var dates = moment.duration(date.diff(today)).asDays();
```

Always `return 0`. What's wrong?

In the examples that I have seen compare objects of **type string** and I need to compare it with an object of **type moment**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [moment js - two dates difference in number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600687/moment-js-two-dates-difference-in-number-of-days)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
    var startDate = moment("13/04/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY");
 var currenDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
 var endDate = moment(currenDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var result = 'Diff: ' + endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
    $('#result').html(result);
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffb;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id='test'>Click Me!!!</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

For more info - [moment js - two dates difference in number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600687/moment-js-two-dates-difference-in-number-of-days)

Comment: In this example, compare two objects of type string and I need to compare them with a moment type object. The current date will provide me with a moment object.

Comment: @Bibi, we can get current date as a string `var currenDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: currenDate.diff is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Based on the the `moment.js` [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/), Let's check what they suggest:

```
var dateA = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var dateB = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
dateA.diff(dateB, 'days'); // result is 1
```

Try this way, might this resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var toDay= moment();
var startDate = moment('2017-11-09');
console.log('Milliseconds:',toDay.diff(startDate));
console.log('days:', toDay.diff(startDate, 'days'), 'days');
console.log('months:', toDay.diff(startDate, 'months'));
```

Comment: var toDay= moment();
      var startDate = moment(stringDate);
      console.log('Milliseconds:',toDay.diff(startDate));
      console.log('days:', toDay.diff(startDate, 'days'), 'days');
      console.log('months:', toDay.diff(startDate, 'months'));

Comment: Milliseconds: NaN
days: NaN days
months: NaN

Comment: Check with "stringDate" variable. var stringDate='2017-09-23'; then use above diff method.