# Non UTC and UTC date comparaison result differs

Tags: javascript

We use a method to calculate days difference between two dates:

```
function getDiffDateInDays(date1: Date, date2: Date): number {
    let diffDays;

    if (date1 && date2) {
      const diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
      diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    }
    return diffDays;
  }
```

After we had some issues on our CI runner (runner runs on a machine sets with UTC time) and locally, we saw some difference in our method result depending on the timezone.

```
const date2 = new Date(2018, 2, 6);
const date3 = new Date(2018, 3, 12);

getDiffDateInDays(date2, date3) => -36
```

Using UTC:

```
const date2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 2, 6));
const date3 = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 3, 12));

getDiffDateInDays(date2, date3) => -37
```

Can anyone explain us why this result differs? The number of days between the two dates should be identical with any timezone?

Comment: Might want to consider using a library to do this, like [momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600770/111266)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a DST switchover between those dates on your timezone which adds or subtracts an hour, which leads to a whole day of difference the way you're `ceil`ing the calculation.

UTC is DST-free and doesn't have that extra/missing hour.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks for explaination!