# How to get difference between two dates in years and months using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am currently getting the difference between two dates in months using the following line:

`_result = Math.abs(moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'months')) + 1;`

As a result I am getting an integer back that displays the duration in number of months. Now I want to change the format of the output and display it exactly in the following format:

`2 years, 3 months`

or in case of year or month being 1 then :

`1 year, 1 month`

How can I reformat my line such that I get this desired result?

NOTE:
I am getting the value in months, as I have mentioned above. I can easily change it to days or years instead of months. But the problem here is that I want to display in the format mentioned above that is, both in years and months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js - two dates difference in number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600687/moment-js-two-dates-difference-in-number-of-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use division and remainder functions

```
var years = Math.floor(months/12);
var months = months % 12;

_result = years + " years, " + months + " months"
```

Comment: How do I send this in _result? How do i declare _result in order to get such an input correctly?

Comment: How about `_result = Math.floor((Math.abs(moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'months')) + 1)/12) + " years, " + (Math.abs(moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'months')) + 1) % 12 + " months"`

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Tried it with no errors on my end

Comment: Got it! There was a slight error with putting the brackets. I fixed it and now i am getting the desired result. Thank you very much!