# Using moment to calculate the number of days between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to work out the number of days between 2 dates in Javascript with the following code.

```
    console.log(self.StartDate());
    var start = moment(self.StartDate(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(start);
    console.log(self.EndDate());
    var end = moment(self.EndDate(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(end);
    var duration = moment.duration(start.diff(end));
    console.log(duration);

    //no of days between start and end
    console.log(duration.asDays());
```

console output:

```
Thu Jun 20 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
n {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Thu Jun 20 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}_d: Wed Aug 19 0020 00:00:00 GMT-0001 (British Summer Time) {}_f: "YYYY-MM-DD"_i: Thu Jun 20 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: false_locale: r {_ordinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, _abbr: "en", _ordinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/}_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(3), overflow: 1, charsLeftOver: 49, …}__proto__: Object
Mon Jun 24 2019 15:10:41 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
n {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Mon Jun 24 2019 15:10:41 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
Ea {_milliseconds: -126230400000, _days: 0, _months: 0, _data: {…}, _locale: r}
-1461
```

self.StartDate() is 20/06/2019 and self.EndDate() is 24/06/2019 so I'm exciting the alert to display 4 however it displays -1461.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Stop using alert. Use `console.log` and look at the output in your dev tools console tab. That said, you don't show code that uses the days you claim to be using, so can you show what moment.js thinks is in those two dates (using console.log and then copying the output)?

Comment: `20/06/2019` is not `"YYYY-MM-DD"`

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600687/moment-js-two-dates-difference-in-number-of-days

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans modified the OP

Comment: Where do you get the date data from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your dates are not [formatted the way you tell moment.js they are](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). `20/06/2019` is `DD/MM/YYYY` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`. As per the documentation, non-numeric characters are ignored so `20/06/2019` would be parsed as `2006-20-19`. Since such a date does not exist, Moment.js tries to guess what you actually meant and it comes up with `2020-06-19`:

```js
var start = moment("20/06/2019", "YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(start);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Same thing happens with the end date.

You need to either change the format you tell to Moment.js or fix the start and end dates to use the format you specified, in both cases, you'd get the correct result:

```js
var self = {
    StartDate: () => "20/06/2019",
    EndDate: () => "24/06/2019"
}

var start = moment(self.StartDate(), "DD/MM/YYYY"); //using the correct format
var end = moment(self.EndDate(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
var duration = moment.duration(start.diff(end));

console.log(duration.asDays());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var self = {
    StartDate: () => "2019-06-20", //using dates in the correct format
    EndDate: () => "2019-06-24"
}

var start = moment(self.StartDate(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
var end = moment(self.EndDate(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
var duration = moment.duration(start.diff(end));

console.log(duration.asDays());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work perfectly fine. You should only swap `start` and `end` at the defference calculation to get positive values.

```js
var startDate = moment("2019-06-20", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var endDate = moment("2019-06-24", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var duration = moment.duration(startDate.diff(endDate));

//no of days between start and end
console.log(duration.asDays());


var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
console.log(duration.asDays());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

If you are only interested in the difference calculated in days, this code will be shorter:

```js
var startDate = moment("2019-06-20", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var endDate = moment("2019-06-24", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var diff  = startDate.diff(endDate, 'days');
console.log(diff);


var diff  = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

There has to be some issue with the dates themselves.
And in fact, it's the way you parse the date strings

```js
// This is parsed as the 19th day of 6th month in year 2020
var startDate = moment("20/06/2019", "YYYY-MM-DD");
// This is parsed as the 19th day of 6th month in year 2024
var endDate = moment("24/06/2019", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var diff  = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
console.log({"start": startDate, "end": endDate, "diff": diff});

// You either need to change the date strings or the format strings
var startDate = moment("20/06/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment("24/06/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var diff  = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
console.log({"start": startDate, "end": endDate, "diff": diff});


// You either need to change the date strings or the format strings
var startDate = moment("2019-06-20", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var endDate = moment("2019-06-24", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var diff  = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
console.log({"start": startDate, "end": endDate, "diff": diff});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: "*Your code should work perfectly fine*" it doesn't. The dates are wrong.

Comment: No, the date strings were there from the beginning. Check [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738328/using-moment-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-2-dates/56738454?noredirect=1#comment100035425_56738328) from 3 minutes after posting the question. I know that the edit history omits recent enough edits but I do know I saw the dates immediately.

Comment: There were no dates presented with the format at the first time of writing.

Comment: Then how was I able to include the exact date that OP used in my comment?

Comment: It was an assumption. I made the same assumption and tried out the days diff between my assumed date format and it matched the calculated diff in the OP.   
I assume! :)

Comment: So, I assumed that the text "*self.StartDate() is 20/06/2019 and self.EndDate() is 24/06/2019*" was there [in the first recorded revision, before the first recorded edit by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56738328/1)? Wait, how did I guess *the exact date* that OP used, not just the format?

Comment: It's the text under the console output. Note that those are not strings, but British English dates. But I think discussing this further is nitpicking

Answer (score -1):

Your date is invalid, you specified a start date of "20/06/2019" which is a template of "DD/MM/YYYY", but told moment to use the template of "YYYY-MM-DD".

You simply need to replace the template that you pass to moment, and here is a bit cleaner way to do it:

```
const DEFAULT_DATE_TEMPLATE = "DD/MM/YYYY";

const getDaysBetweenDates = (date1, date2, dateTemplate = DEFAULT_DATE_TEMPLATE) => {
    const start = moment(date1, dateTemplate);
    const end = moment(date2, dateTemplate);
    const duration = moment.duration(start.diff(end));
    const daysDiff = duration.asDays();

    // for your example you will get -4, abs will make it into 4 for you
    return Math.abs(daysDiff); 
}


const myDiff = getDaysBetweenDates('20/06/2019', '24/06/2019');
console.log(myDiff); // 4

// or if you rather keep your other template
const myDiff2 = getDaysBetweenDates('2019-06-20', '2019-06-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(myDiff2); // 4
```