# How to Calculate difference between two dates with yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffff date-time format

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I want to calculate the difference of days from the date & time `2021-02-23T08:31:37.1410141` `(yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffff)` which comes from the server which is in string format, with the current date-time in angular.

I tried using

```
const daysDiff = Math.floor(Math.abs(<any>fromDate - <any>toDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
```

but it's not working for me. How can I calculate the day difference?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600770/8951175) answer maybe it can fix your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const date1 = new Date("2021-02-23T08:31:37.1410141"); 
const date2 = new Date(); 
const diffTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
const diffDays = Math.floor(Math.abs(diffTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?
`Date.now() - <old date timestamp>`
this gives the difference in miliseconds

So to calculate the difference in days we use:
`Math.floor((Date.now() - <old date timestamp>) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))`

Comment: it's not helping me, can you give me a working code snippet?

Comment: assume the date is coming from the server is in string format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for some time with receiving data like `2020-11-12T12:18:58.019+03:30` but I handled it with this piece of code :

```
          const date = createAt.substr(0, 10);
      const time = createAt.substr(11, 19).split('.')[0];
      if (date === '0001-01-01') {
        return '';
      } else {
        return (
          time +
          ' - ' +
          moment(date, 'YYYY-M-D').locale('fa').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
        );
      }
```

since you are receiving a string of data as big as 27 you have to change the `.substr(0, 10)` methods according to your needs